# faiss-gpu installation unsuccessful for python 3.8 version

Tags: python, gpu

tried to install python faiss-gpu library using pip.

```
Collecting faiss-gpu
  Using cached faiss-gpu-1.7.1.post2.tar.gz (40 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
  WARNING: Generating metadata for package faiss-gpu produced metadata for project name faiss-cpu. Fix your #egg=faiss-gpu fragments.
Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/76/47d0cc8161f4bf988583a2839bb1e56baf09d6b80cfa472b9eba4d5f543b/faiss-gpu-1.7.1.post2.tar.gz (from https://py
pi.org/simple/faiss-gpu/): Requested faiss-cpu from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/76/47d0cc8161f4bf988583a2839bb1e56baf09d6b80cfa472b9eba4d5f543b/fais
s-gpu-1.7.1.post2.tar.gz has inconsistent name: expected 'faiss-gpu', but metadata has 'faiss-cpu'
  Using cached faiss-gpu-1.7.1.post1.tar.gz (41 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
  WARNING: Generating metadata for package faiss-gpu produced metadata for project name faiss-cpu. Fix your #egg=faiss-gpu fragments.
Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/8d/b62bc92c8dd4b2a99d4a06b8804280f6445748b6d698eabb037e111080c7/faiss-gpu-1.7.1.post1.tar.gz (from https://py
pi.org/simple/faiss-gpu/): Requested faiss-cpu from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/8d/b62bc92c8dd4b2a99d4a06b8804280f6445748b6d698eabb037e111080c7/fais
s-gpu-1.7.1.post1.tar.gz has inconsistent name: expected 'faiss-gpu', but metadata has 'faiss-cpu'
  Using cached faiss-gpu-1.7.1.tar.gz (40 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
  WARNING: Generating metadata for package faiss-gpu produced metadata for project name faiss-cpu. Fix your #egg=faiss-gpu fragments.
Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/85/7a7490dbecaea9272953b88e236a45fe8c47571a069bc28b352f0b224ea3/faiss-gpu-1.7.1.tar.gz (from https://pypi.org
/simple/faiss-gpu/): Requested faiss-cpu from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/85/7a7490dbecaea9272953b88e236a45fe8c47571a069bc28b352f0b224ea3/faiss-gpu-
1.7.1.tar.gz has inconsistent name: expected 'faiss-gpu', but metadata has 'faiss-cpu'
  Using cached faiss-gpu-1.7.0.tar.gz (34 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
  WARNING: Generating metadata for package faiss-gpu produced metadata for project name faiss-cpu. Fix your #egg=faiss-gpu fragments.
Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/15/289ecf5d23f209c4c6f2f5f4db1d2b4a2be22d1fc49619354363e9367c19/faiss-gpu-1.7.0.tar.gz (from https://pypi.org
/simple/faiss-gpu/): Requested faiss-cpu from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/15/289ecf5d23f209c4c6f2f5f4db1d2b4a2be22d1fc49619354363e9367c19/faiss-gpu-
1.7.0.tar.gz has inconsistent name: expected 'faiss-gpu', but metadata has 'faiss-cpu'
  Using cached faiss-gpu-1.6.5.tar.gz (28 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
  WARNING: Generating metadata for package faiss-gpu produced metadata for project name faiss-cpu. Fix your #egg=faiss-gpu fragments.
Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/27/3477c856ea3d678619c33ae72f89ede4fbe08e9c5ba3b89a5feb3d9938b0/faiss-gpu-1.6.5.tar.gz (from https://pypi.org
/simple/faiss-gpu/): Requested faiss-cpu from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/27/3477c856ea3d678619c33ae72f89ede4fbe08e9c5ba3b89a5feb3d9938b0/faiss-gpu-
1.6.5.tar.gz has inconsistent name: expected 'faiss-gpu', but metadata has 'faiss-cpu'
  Using cached faiss-gpu-1.6.4.post2.tar.gz (25 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
  WARNING: Generating metadata for package faiss-gpu produced metadata for project name faiss-cpu. Fix your #egg=faiss-gpu fragments.
Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/00/b3aaad408a44e4f5d87ebfcd75d0b14eeaed9fe9bc7a9f5e185ff1d503d6/faiss-gpu-1.6.4.post2.tar.gz (from https://py
pi.org/simple/faiss-gpu/): Requested faiss-cpu from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/00/b3aaad408a44e4f5d87ebfcd75d0b14eeaed9fe9bc7a9f5e185ff1d503d6/fais
s-gpu-1.6.4.post2.tar.gz has inconsistent name: expected 'faiss-gpu', but metadata has 'faiss-cpu'
  Using cached faiss-gpu-1.6.4.tar.gz (3.4 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\python_projects\chatbot_new\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "c:\python_projects\chatbot_new\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "c:\python_projects\chatbot_new\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\panasa154user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uahimyxw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_b
uild_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\panasa154user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uahimyxw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_require
s
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\panasa154user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uahimyxw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\panasa154user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-uahimyxw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Is your question how you can install numpy?

Answer (score 0):

What `pip` is doing in your case is that it grabs the source distribution from Pypi and tries to compile it. This fails, due to incorrect Metadata, something which is an [open issue on github)[https://github.com/kyamagu/faiss-wheels/issues/77].

Looking at the README of the same github however, the recommendation to build a GPU package seems to be to run

```
export FAISS_ENABLE_GPU=ON
pip install --no-binary :all: faiss-cpu
```

so it looks like compiling the source distribution of `faiss-gpu` was never intended